# Splitting by pipe in Java yields different results

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split, guava

Before anyone jumps to conclusions, **yes, I am aware of the need to escape the pipe symbol** :-)

... and in my code, I have done so:

```
String line = "C0000005|A13433185|SCUI|RB|C0036775|A7466261|SCUI||R86000559||MSHFRE|MSHFRE|||N||"
line = line.trim();
String[]     columns_array = line.trim().split("\\|");           // length = 15
List<String> columns_list  = Splitter.on("|").splitToList(line); // size   = 17
```

I am parsing a huge file (~5GB) where each line is pipe-delimited, and the above `line` is the first in that file, where my code crashes with an index out of bounds error. Upon debugging, I realized what was happening, and added the guava `Splitter` line just as a sanity check. Using splitter, I am getting the expected list.

*Why are the results from guava splitter and native split different?*

Comment: Side question: is your file a CSV using a different delimiter? Might save you some trouble to use a CSV library.

Comment: Use `split("\\|", -1);`.

Comment: Yes, 17 ... corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation for `String.split()` says:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Your list is truncated because of this fact.

You can use the following to produce the correct result, as one commenter already pointed out:

```
String[] columns_array = line.trim().split("\\|", -1);  // length 17
```

The API for the `split(String s, int n)` function accepting multiple args:

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length

Answer (score 6):

`String.split()` removes trailing empty strings from the resulting array. And you have two delimiters at the end of the string being split (`...||`).

Here's an excerpt from the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

Comment: Yes.  However, the two-arg version of `String.split()` can be used to produce the same result as guava apparently does.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes, the `limit` argument has to be set to a negative integer, e.g. `"my|string||".split("\\|", -1)`. But IMHO, the `-1` looks artificial, and Guava version looks slightly more readable — it's a matter of personal taste, though.